# Exporting all objects in database (tables,primary / foreign keys, etc..)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am running SQL Server 2008 R2 and I am having trouble exporting the relationships between the tables (i.e. foreign key/primary keys, indexes, etc..)

My goal is to export everything related to the database (expect for the data) and import it into an Entity relationship diagram (there are over 100 tables).

If someone would provide the steps how to export I would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Export it to what format?

Answer (score 2):

You want to script the database.

In SQL Server Management Studio, right click on the database.  Then choose `Tasks-->Generate Scripts`.  This brings up the SQL Server Scripts Wizard.

You can probably take it from there.  The wizard asks what scripts and what objects you want to create.